# Permanently Sync a wiimote with a computer

Tags: wii, bluetooth

i have tried to look up many ways to sync up my wiimotes to my computer so that i can program games with it, but every time it only syncs them up temporarily, or if it says it can permanently sync it, it doesn't actually do it. it gets tiresome when i have to keep on reconnecting it every time i want to save battery life. how would i be able to sync up my wiimote to my computer so that if i turn off my wiimote, i can just hit any button and it will automatically sync it up?

Edit: I have looked here: http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote under Bluetooth pairing for some advice, but I have no idea how to export the char array to the window (i am using the standard pairing with a Bluetooth device, but instead of pairing without a code, i use the "enter device's pairing code" section. this should work, but I'm stuck at how to enter the weird characters that aren't on the keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with doing this, specifically with the new model of wiimotes that Nintendo has released and has seemed to use to replace the old model.  There is a lot of open source code available for setting it up though.

Here is a link documenting some of the new wiimote plus issues:
http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-emu/issues/detail?id=5011

Also, I would examine how Dolphin deals with syncing.  Hope that helps. :)

Edit: I believe automatic syncing in the way that you described would require you to write software. :/